# Finding if $\sum_{}^{}\frac{\ln k}{k}$ converges or diverge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I find whether the serie

$$\sum_{}^{}\frac{\ln k}{k}$$

converge or diverge using the basic comparison test or limit test.

The part that is confusing me is how to deal with $\ln$.

Comment: Closevoters: this post is already 7 years old. Does it worth closing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You know that the harmonic series $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \dfrac 1k$  diverges.

$\dfrac{\ln k}{k} > \dfrac 1k$ as $k$ grows, indeed, for all $k \gt 3$. You don't even need to know that when exactly, $\dfrac {\ln k}{k}$ exceeds $\dfrac 1k$, only that as $k$  grows large (indeed, very early on), $\dfrac{\ln k}{k} \gt \dfrac 1k.$

So you can use the comparison test for convergence/divergence.

---

Added for clarification about the harmonic series and its general term $a_n = \dfrac 1n$:
In a follow-up question below, it was asked why the harmonic series diverges even though the limit as $n \to \infty$ of the general term is zero?

Recall that with respect to the convergence behavior of a given series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$,

> "**IF** $\;\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n| \neq 0,\;$ then it diverges."

So this theorem tells us definitely that any such series diverges. What it *doesn't tell us* is what happens when that same limit ***does*** approach $0.\;$ In those cases where $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n| = 0$, as in the case of the general term of the harmonic series, the associated *series* may converge or it may diverge. So that particular theorem is inconclusive in this case.

For a nice discussion about the divergence of the harmonic series, with proofs of its divergence (using the comparison test and one using the integral test), see the Wikipedia entry on the [divergence of the harmonic series.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Divergence)

Comment: oh so it diverges

Comment: Yes, indeed it does!

Comment: Because $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ is a harmonic series

Comment: Precisely! And the harmonic series diverges, as you know.

Comment: It is strange the harmonic serie diverges if you take the limit of k at infinity it is zero.

Comment: Nice.........+1

Comment: @FernandoMartinez, you're confusing between the *sequence* and its *series*.

Comment: Fernando, here is something more mindboggling. Why don't you replace the k by, say 1000k. So 1000k is in the denominator. Then this series STILL diverges...How is that??

Comment: @amWhy: Hopes it makes a nice answer! +1

Comment: You can also note that $$\frac 1 2(\log^2 x)'=\frac{\log x}x$$

Comment: Fernando: Recall that for series, we know only that "if the limit of the absolute value of the general term does not approach $0$, then it diverges." But this theorem *doesn't tell us* what happens when that same limit ***does*** approach $0$. In the case where $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n| = 0$, as in the case of the general term of the harmonic series, the associated *series* may converge or it may diverge. So that particular theorem is inconclusive in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: $\dfrac{\ln k}{k} > \dfrac1k$ for $k \geqslant 3$.

Comment: Hmm But does it have to be for k>=3 because if you plug in k=1 ln(k)/k is zero and 1/k is one

Comment: Actually because $e < 3$, i.e. $\ln k > 1$ if $k\ge 3$.

Answer (score 1):

The Comparison Test: Suppose that $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are series with positive terms.

(i) If $\sum b_n$ is convergent and $a_n\le b_n$ for all $n$, then $\sum a_n$ is also convergent.

(ii) If $\sum b_n$ is divergent and $a_n\ge b_n$ for all $n$, then $\sum a_n$ is also divergent.

Consider the Harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k}$. We know that this series diverges. Using the Comparison Test we know that ${\ln k\over k}>{1\over k}$ for $k\ge3$. Thus the given series is divergent by the Comparison Test.

Comment: Also you may use the integral test by checking convergence or divergence of the integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x}dx$.

Comment: Absolutely! Also, that integral is quite pleasant :) I will add that to my post as another approach. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the integral test. The series

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(k)}{k}
$$

converges if and only if the integral

$$
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \,dx
$$

converges. Letting $u = \ln(x)$ we get $du = \frac{1}{x} \,dx$ so we obtain

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} u \, du = \left[ \frac{u^2}{2} \right]^{\infty}_{0} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \left[ \frac{u^2}{2} \right]^t_0
$$

which tends to infinity, implying that the series is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

use limit test where
where numerater is given function and denominater is g(x)=1/x
as n->infinite limit 'l' also tends to infinite.
so if limit is infinite 
denomnater diverges implies numerater diverges.
since g(n)=1/n diverges =>given series diverges